# Animated/timed text with JavaScript return

Tags: javascript, return

I have the following code:

```
function list() {
    return "blob1<br>blob2<br>blob3";
}
```

When this code is run, it directly displays the whole text in `return` on the call of the function.

Is there a way to make it display `blob1`, then wait for 0.5 seconds, then display `blob2`, then after 0.5 more seconds display `blob3`?

Comment: Well, to clarify, this function doesn't "display" anything. It returns some HTML as a string, and the presumption is somewhere else it puts that HTML on the page. I think that that second block of code is what you need to be showing, for us to work off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I might do it:

```js
var stack = ["blob1", "blob2", "blob3"];

function nextItem() {
    document.body.innerHTML += stack.shift() + "<br>";
}

nextItem();
setTimeout(nextItem, 500);
setTimeout(nextItem, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout) to delay the execution of a function:

```js
var text = ["blob1", "blob2", "blob3"],
    target = document.getElementById('target');
(function display() {
    if(!text.length) return;
    target.textContent = text.shift();
    setTimeout(display, 500);
})();
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: `textContent` might not work with the `<br/>` elements he had before. It might be something you could work into the example through `createElement/appendChild` though.

Comment: Your answer is quite interesting, but I'd like them to be showing under each other (with line breaks).

Answer (score 0):

```
function list(num) {
    return "blob" + num;
}

var num = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    list(num);
    num ++;
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfhxgenf/

So this code is calling the list function every half a second and sending in a number. The number gets incremented by 1 every time the interval is ran.

The list function will return blob1, blob2, blob3, blob4, blob5, and so on, every half a second.

Check out the jsfiddle and open the console to see the result.

Also, I'm assuming you're doing something further with this string. Right now it's not being displayed anywhere.

And, if you only want it to go to 3 you can add a check to destroy the interval when the num gets to 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/yfhxgenf/1/